# My engine does't pick up when headlight are ON

Tags: engine

Suppose I am running my car which is maruti baleno 2018 model 2nd generation  at a speed of 50 constant speed,with my headlight ON. Now suddenly I feel my car loses pick up and feel jerk, after that I accelerate my car but it didn't I pressed the pedal maximum but car will not pick up the speed, now when I turnoff the headlights the pickup will be there.

Comment: Original battery or was it replaced? If original, it may be worn out as the alternator is attempting to charge the battery while supplying all the electrical needs of the vehicle, possibly overloading the alternator that takes power away from the 1.2L engine.

Comment: Yes, It was replaced. So do I need to check for the alternator or battery. How I get to know which is faulty. Thanks in advance

Comment: If you have a multimeter, measure battery voltage with engine off; it should be around 12.5vdc. If less, have battery tested and recharged. Examine the drive belt; it should be tight, not loose as the engine must turn the drive belt to run the alternator, water and power steering pump. If the drive belt is loose, the alternator may not output power to recharge the battery and operate the vehicle electrical system. With engine idling, measure battery voltage again; it should be around 14.5vdc as the alternator is outputting power for the car while recharging the battery.

Comment: Ok, I will check this and come back to you. But what if everything is well multimeter shows the correct reading then, there is a chance of a faulty alternator and I have to replace it.
I don't think the belt is loose because if it looses then there will be some sound coming from engine, but there is no sound are coming from engine.

Comment: The issue is due to my broken tail light, Because of this water entered the hole into the tail light and caused the issue I removed my headlight plug then I tested this and got to know about the issue. I ordered the tail light to test it further and confirm this.

Comment: Thank you for following up on your dilemma with additional info of a tail light issue causing the problem.